# Pathological mechanisms in asthma

Tags: pathology

What is known about the precise molecular mechanisms involved in asthma?  For instance, is it known why the bronchi tissue alteration cannot be reversed?  Were any new mechanisms discovered in the last decade or so?

Comment: I don't know the answer myself off-hand, but this seems like a rather basic question, so you should probably look it up somewhere else (such as Wikipedia, or a medical textbook) rather than asking people to explain it here.  On this site you're only supposed to ask for information that you couldn't easily get ready-made.  If you *have* in fact looked it up already without success, you'll get a better reception if you say so and tell them something about where you've already looked.

Comment: Yes I understand, but my hope was that someone who knows well that topic could give me the great lines, so that I could find by myself the details more easily.